# Custom User attributes values not stored in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have created some custom attributes in Azure AD B2C. When i signup usign userflow , i am noticing that the custom attribute values are not stored in Active directory. I am checking the active directory in Users -> user profile.
Only the built in values are available. Custom attributes are not even mentioned in it. Can anyone help me with this?

[User Option I opted to check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwULJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only basic user attributes appear in the Azure Portal. Find the full attribute set using MS Graph API beta /users endpoint.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: So you mean we can't view custom attribute details in Active directory. We have to fetch them into our web application side?

Comment: You just cannot see them in the Portal. You can fetch them via Graph API, or insert them into the Token (using Application Claims menu in your User Flow) so you dont have to fetch them via Graph API. If you are trying to do User Management type ops, then yes, the only way is through your User Management Application.

Comment: I am able to fetch the user data . This solution helped better with my requirement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903001/how-to-get-list-of-users-from-my-azure-ad-b2c-in-asp-net-core-mvc-app. But even your answer helped me because the link i have mentioned had some small code changes required which i got from your link. Atleast i got to know this is the way to fetch user info. Not from azure portal. Thanks a lot :)